# Sort/Filter ObservableList which holds duplicate entries and display as TreeTableView

Tags: java, javafx-8

i have an ObservableList which holds objects of type Auftrag.
The object Auftrag has a property NR which could occur multiple times(duplicates) in the ObservableList but the other property content differs.

I try to use this to show all entries with the same NR under a root TreeItem.

Now i try to display the data in a TreeTableView where the first NR item string of a bunch of Auftrag objects should be the root TreeItem and the following items with the same NR should be the child TreeItems.

Here is the problem. Only the first item is displayed and in it all the others.
Here´s some example code first create the TreeTableView

```
@FXML
private TreeTableView<Auftrag> abTreeTable;
```

now create a column and set root and add column

```
TreeTableColumn<Auftrag,String> nrTreeCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("NR");
nrTreeCol.setMinWidth(80);
nrTreeCol.setCellValueFactory(
(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Auftrag,String> param) ->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<String>(param.getValue().getValue().getNR()));
abTreeTable.setRoot(createTreeStructure(u));
abTreeTable.getColumns().add(nrTreeCol);
```

and here i create the structure

```
private TreeItem createTreeStructure(ObservableList<Auftrag> items){
    int itemcount = items.size();
    TreeItem<Auftrag> main = new TreeItem<Auftrag>(items.get(0));
    for (int i =1; i < itemcount; i++) {
        String ab = items.get(i).getNR();
        ObservableList<Auftrag> same = getSameAuftrag(items,ab);
        TreeItem<Auftrag> root = new TreeItem<Auftrag>(items.get(i));
        same.forEach(item->{
            TreeItem<Auftrag> child = new TreeItem<Auftrag>(item);
            root.getChildren().add(child);
        });
        main.getChildren().add(root);
    }

    return main;
```

here the look up for same NRs is done but does´t seem to work right

```
private ObservableList<Auftrag> getSameAuftrag(ObservableList<Auftrag> items, String ab){
        ObservableList<Auftrag> same = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).getNR() == ab){
                same.add(items.get(i));
            }
        }

        return same;
    }
```

and it looks like this

[image: root TreeItem and all other items are child]

Here you see that the getSameAuftrag function seems to not work correctly because there are five NRs with the same string those should be in a root node...

[image: three times same NR]

What i expect is a root row(TreeItem) with the NR as title and if i expand it should show all child TreeItems with the same NR...

Hope someone could help

Comment: Not sure I completely follow your logic, but you need to compare `String`s for equality using `.equals(...)`, not `==`. I.e. `if (items.get(i).getNR().equals(ab))`

Comment: Arrrggg should sleep a bit more :) Thx so much!